# Twilio - international calls hang up too soon

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

We are calling from the US to the Middle East using Twilio to play notification messages to contacts. This works to users in the US, Canada, Europe etc. but in some Middle East countries there is a significant delay before the user's handset receives the signal and begins to ring. What is happening is that Twilio is hanging up the call after 15 seconds, but it is taking around 15 seconds for the contacts' handsets to ring.
I cannot see anything in the documentation or API that relates to how long Twilio should wait before hanging up the call.

Does anybody know of a way to increase this timeout? I see nothing in the Twiml spec...